# Prove that if $|A+A| \leq K|A|$ then $2A - 2A$ is a $K^{16}$-approximate group.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, abelian-groups, additive-combinatorics, sumset

Let $A$ be a finite subset of an abelian group, $G$ (call the operation addition). We say $A$ is a $K$-approximate group if:

1) $e_G \in A$

2) $A^{-1} = \{ a^{-1} \mid a \in A \} = A$

3) $\exists X \subset G, \; |X| \leq K$ such that: $2A \subset X+A$

Where: $A+A = \{a+b \mid a,b \in A\}$

I am asked to show that if $|A+A| \leq K|A|$, then $2A - 2A$ is a $K^{16}$-approximate group.

To this end, I am not entirely sure where to start. The first two properties fall out reasonably easily.

I believe it is well known that $|2A - 2A| \leq K^4|A|$

I am aware of a result that allows me to find an $X \subset G, \; |X| \leq K^4 $ such that $nA - A \subset (n-1)X + A - A$, which I believe implies:

$2A \subset X+A$

What can I do now though? I don't see how I can get the required subset of $G$, and the corresponding bound on the size?

Comment: What is $K{}{}{}?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $K$ is a constant such that $|A+A| \leq K|A|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $nA-A\subset(n-1)X+A-A$, take $n=2$ to get 
  $$ 2A-A\subset X+A-A. $$
It follows that 
  $$ 2A-2A \subset X+A-2A = X - (2A-A) \subset X-X+A-A. $$
This yields
  $$ 4A-4A \subset 2(X-X) + (2A-2A). $$
In view of $|2(X-X)|\le|X|^4\le K^{16}$, this shows that $2A-2A$ is a $K^{16}$-approximate group